# Why are there posters of the film inside Micmacs à Tire-Larigot?

Tags: micmacs, posters

In Jean-Pierre Jeunet's Micmacs à Tire Larigot, there are several occurrences where we can see the posters of the film in the movie sets or on props.

What's the meaning of this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]